# HTML Drop down list onchange

Tags: menu, onchange, window.open, dropdown

I have a small DropDownList with 3 options .
Problem is when I select , let's say , 2nd option .
No probs , a new page is opened .

If I click on option 1 or 3 , no probs .
However ,  if I click on 2nd option again , instead of clicking on 1 or 2 , no new page is opened .

Is there a way to correct this , so that clicking on whatever always opens a new window .

Thanks...Vern

SORRY I COULDN'T GET THE "CODE" OR "HTML" TO WORK .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>myFavs-HtmlProbs.html</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="PureBasic">
<meta name="Description" content="Your description here...">
<meta name="Description" content="...Created by  myFavs % PureBasic...">
<style type="text/css">
</style> 
</head>
<body text="#000000" style="background-color:#A69E80; text-align:center;">
<br> <br> <br>
<!--dd <div style=-->
<table width="100%" border="0" style="text-align:center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr style="text-align:center">
<!-- EXAMPLE: <MenuName="aaMost-Used"> -->   <!-- rgb(250,240,255) -->
<select style="width:200px; font:14px Arial Black; color:rgb(0,0,0); background-color:rgb(231,169,126);" name="menu" onchange="window.open(this.value)">
<option selected="0" value="">aaMost-Used</option>
<option value="http://alternativeto.net/">AlternativeToSoftwares</option>
<option value="https://www.biblegateway.com/reading-plans/chronological/today?version=NLT">One Year Chronological Bible NLT</option>
<option value="http://www.portablefreeware.com/">portablefreeware.com/</option>
</select></td></tr></table><br></body></html>
```

Comment: i tried your code its working fine...
what is the exact issue....all options opens the new window

Comment: Its because your action is `onchange`, so if you select the same option more than once it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this attribute to your `select` tag

```
onfocus="this.selectedIndex=0;"
```

It will change the option to the default option each time after you select one, in your case 
 *aaMost-Used* and hence you can then select your required next option again.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an option more than once, it does not open the page because the option is already selected, and no change occurs. Therefore, `onchange` isn't fired.

You can actually open a link twice by opening that link, opening another (deselects first) and then clicking on the first link again.

**But here's the fix.**
Change `onchange="window.open(this.value)"` to `onclick="window.open(this.value)"` (`onchange` to `onclick`).

That way, the link will be opened whenever an option is clicked, rather than when it changes.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SanPilot/mqqh5u73/1/

Comment: `onclick` won't work as it will just fire the selected option on just clicking the dropdown menu.You won't be able to choose.

Comment: @wolfsgang It seems to be working fine for me on Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/SanPilot/mqqh5u73/1/

Comment: you are able to choose from the dropdown using the mouse click?Because its on default and trying to bring down the menu by clicking just opens up an empty tab,as it should because it will respond on any mouse click on the element.I would have to scroll using the keyboard every time and then click.

Comment: @wolfsgang Which browser are you using? I suspect that the difference is between browsers.